# What is the best way to get an integer into an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

Criteria: Performance, Performance, Performance.

I need a way to convert a uint, int, etc into it's enum equivalent.  What's the fastest way I can do that using C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why can't you just do a direct cast?

```
MyEnum enumVar = (MyEnum)intVar;
```

Comment: Argg, was just gonna say that :)

Comment: I know.  That happens to me all the time. ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Wow, that was much easier then some other weird solutions I saw out there.

Comment: Enums to and from ints is trivial.  In fact, I'm pretty sure that the compiler handles 99% of any optimizations that you would need to worry about.  Now when you go back and forth from strings is where it can get funky.

Comment: The only problem with this is that you can cast values that are invalid and you won't get an exception. Enum.Parse() is much safer, but it does involve overhead from a performance perspective.